# undefined method `destroy_user_session_path' for active admin with cancancan and sorcery

Tags: activeadmin, sorcery

HI I am working on rails 4.2.4 app and i am using sorcery for authentication, cancancan for authorization.. so far so good i can login and users can do as well .... I am trying to add activeadmin for admin dashboard I so far set up almost everything but when i fire up the link http://localhost:3000/admin when logged in the app as admin i get the error :

undefined method `destroy_user_session_path' for         
:ActiveAdmin::Views::TabbedNavigation

here are my modules:

Activeadmin.rb

```
ActiveAdmin.setup do |config|

  config.site_title = "title goes here"

  def authenticate_user!
    if !current_user.admin?
     redirect_to new_user_session_path
    end


end

  config.authentication_method = :authenticate_user!
  config.current_user_method = :current_user
  config.logout_link_method = :delete
  config.logout_link_path = :destroy_user_session_path
  config.batch_actions = true
  config.authorization_adapter = ActiveAdmin::CanCanAdapter
  config.localize_format = :long

end
```

ability.rb

```
    class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new

    if user.admin?
      can :read, ActiveAdmin::Page, :name => "Dashboard"
      can :manage, :all
    elsif user.client?
      can :manage, [Act, Do, Fact, Task, T]
      cannot :read, ActiveAdmin::Page, :name => "Dashboard"
    else
      can :read, Activity
    end

    can :manage, UserSessionsController do |user_session|
      user == user_session
    end

    if user.active?
      can :time, Activity
      can :read, ActiveAdmin::Page, :name => "Dashboard"
    end
    can :log_in, User
    can :log_out, User
    can :reset_password, User
  end
end
```

destroy in sessions controller

```
def destroy
    authorize! :log_out, User
    logout
    redirect_to root_url, notice: I18n.t('users.log_out')
  end
```

Can anyone point me on how to solve this .... been stuck here for a while ...

cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so after investigating further the correct way is

config.logout_link_path = :user_session_path

But sadly ActiveAdmin don't support urls with ids at logout path at the moment.

see this thread [from the activeadmin owner](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/4220)